# Drop member failed for DatabaseRole 'db_owner'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create new user in `SQL Server 2014` I just want to give Read Access to user but when I assign db_datareader role I am getting above error

> Drop member failed for DatabaseRole 'db_owner'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Please help me on this Thanks

Comment: Have you tried T-SQL: `ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER SomeUser;`?

Comment: I didn't tried yet, I am just checking now if any other database is hold up by same username.

Comment: In your case, you're going to want to try running `alter role db_owner drop member [whateverUser]` and see what error you get from the database. Using the GUI is nice, but in this case it's hiding the error from you.

Comment: Actually when I deleted user from Login section I forgot that I also need to remove user from assigned Database. So again when I tried to create new user with same name it giving such error.